# Site icons being messed up

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just noticed that PPCG now has Code Review's icon in some areas of SE. I'm pretty sure this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) since I can't find any discussion related to it.

Basically the problem seems to appear wherever [the site sprite sheet](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=0b5182b5ddfc) is used. Looking closer, it seems that every site's icon is off by two (one site + one meta).

**Update:** Looking at the [stylesheet](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/all.css?v=2f76593bf94d) and [sprite sheet](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=0b5182b5ddfc) the problem seems to be that the version of the sprite sheet I'm seeing has no icons for [Augur](https://augur.stackexchange.com/). Version mismatch?

**Update 2:** Seems to be fixed. Anyone still experiencing this?

#### Top bar menus

[image: stackexchange menu]
[image: inbox]
[image: achievements]

#### Sidebar hot questions

[image: sidebar hot questions]

#### User communities list

[image: community list]

#### Things not affected

So far I haven't seen this anywhere else, including the favicon, [the global hot question list](https://stackexchange.com/) and [the site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#).

Comment: No repro here...

Comment: This might be more suited to Meta.SE, because it affects all the sites, not just PPCG

Comment: Can't recreate the issue, either.

Comment: Might be a (server level) caching issue then. Clearing browser cache did nothing. If anyone else can reproduce, please comment.

Comment: I have this same issue. Seems that some sites are not affected (like Academia and AskUbuntu), but most are and have a wrong icon.

Comment: Last one is Dennis's profile right?

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Comment: This was affecting [super user also](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39188456#39188456).

Comment: I have this issue as well. I'm running Firefox on Debian Linux, if that makes a difference. Interestingly, the Firefox app on my Android phone shows correct icons.

Comment: Hm, Code Review's logo kind of fits... Maybe we should keep it

Comment: **[Main meta thread.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299205/wrong-icons-in-the-hot-network-questions-column)**

Comment: Should be fixed now. Are you still seeing the mixed up icons?

Comment: [Fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299205/wrong-icons-in-the-hot-network-questions-column).